# how to run batch script file in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

In need to run task scheduler  which runs a batch file i know how to use task scheduler(using spring) but i don't know how to run batch file from hibernate

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to call batch file from java/hibernate.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start build.bat");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is not for scheduling tasks.
For scheduling batch file, you can use Quartz scheduling library. http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

***FYI:***You can use Jsch with Expect4j for executing scripts.